# How create an Global Variable for all the project type NSArray

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, global-variables, nsarray

I would like to know how can I create a global variable type NSArray that i can use (write in/read data) from any class from y app.

At the moment i'm using NSUserDefaults, but I don't think this is the best option, because i'm saving one NSArray quite big.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can either just put it in a global variable (works the same as in C, just declare it at global scope) or, better, put it in [a singleton object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like). Each class that wants to access it would first get the shared instance of the singleton object, which has a reference to your array. If you want the data to be persistent between runs of the application, you can still make sure to save it before quitting the app.

Comment: And of course, to write data to the global variable, it should be an NSMutableArray, which is a subclass of NSArray which the original poster wanted.